# Locking down laptop for use with children

Tags: windows-10

I have a Windows 10 laptop which I'd like to share with my children. As they are young, I don't want them to be able to install software nor change any settings. I also notice that there is software I have installed under my profile which shows up on their profile in the start menu.

Is there any software, or Windows settings that will run when they login which will hide my software from their start menu and prevent them from installing any further software.

I guess this must be similar to situations where you need to lock down certain groups of users limiting their access to certain programs and prevent access to control panel etc to enable a only a specific task to be completed perhaps in an industrial or public environment.

Comment: There are parental controls built into Windows. Do you have a specific question about that feature?

Comment: Read up on the parental controls here: https://www.lifewire.com/microsoft-family-safety-parental-controls-4153037

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Microsoft's Family system for this.

It allows you to set up children's accounts, give appropriate accesses, set up reports so you can see a digest of their activities, and it also allows easy ability for the child to request a special access and you or another parent/guardian to review the request and approve or decline.

Because it's baked into the OS it's decently secure and isn't too easy to get around.

You'll need to be using Microsoft accounts to sign into the computer, and then go to family.microsoft.com to get started.